# Gnuplot - setting of xrange

Tags: gnuplot

How to set this xrange please to see the function g(x) as the gauss function? Thank you

```
c = 299792458
kB = 1.380649*10**(-23)
T = 10000
m_he = 6.64424*10**(-27)
nun_he = 4.55746e+14
nuth_he = (2*kB*T/m_he)**(0.5)
konst2 = 11e+12

g(x) = 1-konst2/((pi)**(0.5)*(nuth_he))*exp(-((x-nun_he)**2)/(nuth_he**2))

set xtics rotate by -90

set term pngcairo size 800,1200 enhanced font "Segoe UI,18"
set output "out.png"

set format y "%4.2sx10^{%T}"       
x0=4.55746e+14
set xrange [x0-0.00001e+14:x0+0.00001e+14]
plot g(x) with lines lw 2.5 linecolor rgb "medium-blue", "<echo '4.55746e+14 1'" with points ls 7 ps 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the basics of the [Gauss function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).
Basically, the factor `σ` determines the width of the peak (in your case `nuth_he`).
So if you choose the range for example `x0-3σ` to `x0+3σ` you should nicely see your curve.

```
x0=4.55746e+14
set xrange [x0-nuth_he*3:x0+nuth_he*3]
```

However, what should this be?

```
"<echo '4.55746e+14 1'" with points ls 7 ps 2
```

Drawing a single point or line? But again, this will be orders of magnitudes different in y from your Gaussian curve. With this point or line in the same plot you won't see a peak or dip of your Gauss curve.

[image]

Comment: a single point e.g. at coordinates `0,0` you also could place as label. `set label 1 at 0,0 point pt 7 ps 2 lc rgb "red"`. Of course before the plot command. Check `help label`.